# Moodle unable to login to my localhost/moodle

Tags: authentication, session-cookies, moodle

After months of inactivity, I returned to working on my localhost/moodle, version 3.1, trying to login as admin i get the error message:  "Unfortunately, cookies are currently not enabled in your browser".

The cookies required are 'MoodleSession' and 'MOODLEID'.

In my Chrome setting i can see 'MoodleSession', but not 'MOODLEID' (and i don't know how to add/enable it) .

Also there is not extra lines or spaces at the end of the file and i have added "?>" to the end of config.php which did not help me to login.

Any feedback as to what else i can do to login to my localhost is appreciated[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzZsB.png).

Answer (score 0):

try accessing the link with https. I had the same issue but working with https.

Comment: Could you elaborate and post some code or some action flow?